# Respectfully scraping data using ActiveJob and Sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, queue, sidekiq, rails-activejob

I'm asynchronously scraping data from around 20-30 different websites using ActiveJob and one Sidekiq queue, `default`.

Currently, added jobs start immediately and hammer the heck out of the hosts I'm scraping.  I'd like to access these websites in a more respectful way but I'm not exactly sure how to configure ActiveJob/Sidekiq.

My idea scenario would achieve the following:

- Jobs targeting a common source must wait at least 30 seconds in between back to back jobs
- Jobs targeting differencing sources can run in parallel
- Attempts to queue identical jobs should be ignored.  In other words, when attempting to queue a job, check if one already exists and don't add it
- Retry jobs should adhere to the same standards

Thank you!